# Is There Svg to html5 svg converter

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Illustrator can output in svg. But Some features of svg aren't straight forward in html5. For example some need to be complemented with prefix. So is there svg editor or converter that takes normal svg and optimize it for web.

I find learning svg to level that's it's useful or doing anything with it extremely unintuitive..and hard. I suppose svg is meant to be created by programs only.

I didn't mean that i wanted to convert svg to canvas...but that there are some features of svg that need to be prefixed. So is there a program that does that.

Comment: Can you be specific as to the features you're having trouble with?

Comment: One simple google search (svg to html5 converter) came up with this: http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Comment: if there would be a way to create <div> elements which look like a tangled path, than, this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most browser support svg nowadays: http://caniuse.com/svg. You should be able to use them directly.

Here is the SVG implementation status in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_in_Firefox

Comment: i mean that if you draw paths in illustrator they do transfer to html5's svg but there are somethings that dont. And need to be prefixed.